# Using python, my eighth element in dictionary prints in the beginning

Tags: python, dictionary

```
testVals = {1001: "AV", 1002: "AV", 1003: "AV", 1004: "AV", 1005: "BV", 1006: "BV", 1007: "BV", 1008: "BV"}
print testVals
```

This prints:
{1008: 'BV', 1001: 'AV', 1002: 'AV', 1003: 'AV', 1004: 'AV', 1005: 'BV', 1006: 'BV', 1007: 'BV'}

What is going on here? Why is the last one indexed at 0 now? I need them to be in order. thanks

Comment: Python `dict` is inherently unordered (except for Python 3.6 currently)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key was the best answer to this frequent duplicate question that I found in a quick search.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I guess I should use tuple for my purpose then.

Comment: Unless you give us context as to why you need it ordered, it would be quite hard to help you make the best choice. One such choice available to you is an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: You're asking basically two things: "Why is it displayed like that" and "How to keep them in order" so I closed your question as duplicate to two questions that deal with these questions. If you think the duplicates don't solve your question: [edit] the question and explain why it's not a duplicate. :)